# Carrierwave resize an image before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave for image uploader and I need to resize the images before they got saved.

In my avatar_uploader.rb I have the following code:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file
  resize_to_fit(150, 150)

  def resize_to_fit(width, height)
    process :resize_to_fit => [width, height]
  end
end
```

But when I  upload an image, the size do not change to 150x150.
Is there any way to resize an image and save it resized(150x150)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the line **config.enable_processing = true**
in my carrierwave.rb

I removed it and now the images are saved 150x150 as I wanted.

The only line that I needed to add in uploader.rb was :
**process resize_to_fill: [150, 150]**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your image resized to exactly 150x150 even if that means cropping the image, you need `resize_to_fill`

From carrierwave

Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the aspect ratio of the original image. If necessary, crop the image in the larger dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I changed the code to **resize_to_fill** but still the images I upload don't change their dimension neither are cropped.

Comment: The problem is the way you are calling It
Define directly in the body of your class: process resize_to_fill => [150,150]

Comment: Thank you again.
I had another problem, I hat to remove the line **config.enable_processing = true* from my carrierwave.rb and now it works

Comment: Right, but anyways resize_to_fill is what you need when enforcing dimensions

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are passing your params correctly? May be its not getting your input there. try sth. like this

```
process :resize_to_fit => [150, 150]
```

ro for specific version:

```
  version :thumbnail do
    process :resize_to_fit => [150, 150]
  end
```

instead of using height, and width..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will do in my own case to refactor your code. When this uploader is used, an uploaded image would be scaled to be no larger than 150 by 150 pixels. A version called thumb is then created, which is scaled and cropped to exactly 190 by 60 pixels

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  process resize_to_fit: [150, 150]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [190, 60]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```